# It is possible use Spark 3.3.0 in AWS Glue 3.0

Tags: apache-spark, aws-glue, aws-glue-spark, aws-glue3.0

I would like to use **Spark 3.3.0** version features like `Trigger.availableNow` in AWS Glue 3.0 with scala, but the AWS Glue 3.0 usage Apache spark version 3.1.1, Is there any way to use apache spark 3.3.0 in AWS Glue 3.0 with scala.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is unfortunately not possible. You can only use the versions that [Glue provides](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/release-notes.html). If you want to use a different Spark version you would have to use [AWS EMR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-release-app-versions-6.x.html), they support Spark 3.2.0.

Comment: I think so, thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

**Spark 3.3.0** is now available with **AWS Glue 4.0** https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/11/introducing-aws-glue-4-0/